# SMTP Telnet and PHP not getting any response from HELO

Tags: php, sockets, smtp, telnet

Ok I'm having my first attempt at socket programming with php, something I've been meaning to do for a while but sped up by the fact our bounced e-mail tracking on an application we've done at work did not work, so now I've got to check a whole of e-mail addresses to make sure their valid.

I've learnt how to use telnet through the command line to validate an e-mail address and to send an e-mail address, and i'm having not problem with that. Where I'm falling down is when I go to use the "HELO" command to communicate with the server.

But I might be in complete the wrong area here as I don't even know if this has established a telnet connection, but the var dump at the end suggests there is a connection being made.

The connection response is the same when I made a telnet connection the command line except for "n6si3992361paw.22" but I imagine that is some sort of unique identifier for each connection.

```
<?php

$target = "aspmx.l.google.com";
$port = 25;
$errno = "";
$errstr = "";
$timeout = 9;
$newline = "\n\r";
$logArray = array();

$connect = fsockopen($target, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
$smtpResponse = fgets($connect, 4096);
if(empty($connect)) {
   $logArray["error"][] = "Failed to connect: $smtpResponse";
   var_dump($logArray);
   exit;
} else {
   $logArray['connection'][] = "Connected to: $smtpResponse";
}
fputs($connect, "HELO" . $newLine);
$smtpResponse = fgets($connect, 4096);
$logArray['connection'][] = "$smtpResponse";
var_dump($logArray);
```

result of $logArray:

```
array(1) { ["connection"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(57) "Connected to: 220 mx.google.com ESMTP n6si3992361paw.22 " [1]=> string(0) "" } }
```

Comment: The SMTP specs say lines must end in CRLF, not LFCR. Try fixing that first.

Comment: No still get the same response. Times out afer a while. $smtpResponse is an empty string. I'm gonna try from a different server and see how that goes.

Comment: FWIW the correct syntax is `HELO example.com` where you'd obviously replace `example.com` with the name of the host you are connecting from.  There is no requirement to speak the truth, so you see a lot of `HELO windows7` or `HELO localhost` but some sites treat those as spam indicators.  Also you definitely want to use `EHLO` instead if you can.

Comment: What's with the `fgets($connect, 4096)`?  If you have to have a number, use something out of the SMTP spec (1000 or 1024 might be good) but don't just blindly guess.

Answer (score 1):

You made a simple typo (PHP variable names are case-sensitive).

Compare this:

```
$newline = "\n\r";
```

... with this:

```
fputs($connect, "HELO" . $newLine);
```

Use `$newline`, not `$newLine`. Then it works.

Also, as Casper already pointed out, you have the order of the CRLF wrong; use `\r\n`, not the other way around.